# Finding "nearly orthogonal" subset of vectors from a set of vectors..

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, orthogonality

Given a set of vectors $V \in \mathbb{R}^n$, is there any algorithm that I can use to find a subset $U \subset V$ of a chosen size $K$ such that the vectors in $U$ are "nearly orthogonal" with each other? By "nearly orthogonal", I mean that for each vector $v_i,v_j \in U$ their dot product $v_i^Tv_j$ is as close to zero as possible? To rephrase it, I am searching for a subset of $V$ of given size where each vectors are "nearly" mutually orthogonal to each other.

So far, my approach has been to brute force it, where, for any given size $K$, I enumerate all possible combinations of vectors in $V$ and calculate their dot products with each other and choose the combination which minimizes the maximum of their mutual dot products. Obviously, this will never scale for a $V$ with large number of vectors. Is there any efficient algorithm for this?

Comment: I have no idea if this will work well, but here is an idea. If $M$ denotes the matrix whose columns are the vectors of $V$, then your question amounts to finding a diagonal matrix $D$ whose entries are $0,1$ where we want $D$ to have a large trace and we want the (perhaps sum of squares of) off-diagonal entries of $M^TDM$ to be small. Perhaps it is useful to consider the (convex?) relaxation of this problem where the entries of $D$ are taken from the interval $[0,1]$. A naive idea might be to take the solution to this problem and round all entries of $D$ to $0$ or $1$.

Comment: I am having a difficult time wrapping my head around your reduction of the problem to the minimization of the sum of squares of the off-diagonal entries of $M^TDM$. Do you perhaps mean $MDM^T$ instead?

Comment: I do not. Note that when the entries of $D$ are taken from $\{0,1\}$, we have
$$
[M^TDM]_{i,j} = \begin{cases}
v_i^T v_j & d_{ii} = d_{jj} = 1\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
where the columns of $M$ are $v_1,v_2,\dots$

Comment: Convex relaxation of the problem indeed sounds appealing and I think I will try it as a baseline, but I wonder if the problem itself is NP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the problem via mixed integer linear programming as follows.  Let binary decision variable $x_i$ indicate whether $i\in U$.  Let $z$ represent the maximum absolute value of dot products of pairs of selected vectors.  The problem is to minimize $z$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_i x_i &= K \tag1\\
z &\ge |v_i^T v_j| (x_i + x_j - 1) &&\text{for $i < j$}\tag2
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ forces exactly $K$ vectors to be chosen.
Constraint $(2)$ enforces $(x_i \land x_j) \implies z \ge |v_i^T v_j|$.

Comment: I think that constraints (2) and (3) don't account for when both $x_i=0$ and $x_j=0$.

Comment: (2) was fine, but (3) was wrong.  I combined them now.  Because $z \ge 0$, the constraint is redundant unless $x_i=x_j=1$.

Comment: Thank you Rob. My set of vectors $V$ contains around $7000$ elements with each vector $\in R^{300}$. I want to select a subset of length $500$. Do you think MIP will scale for a problem of this length? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: The value $n=300$ does not affect the size of the formulation. It is worth trying directly, but two alternatives are to generate constraints $(2)$ dynamically only when they are violated or omit these constraints altogether and replace the minimax objective with a quadratic objective to minimize $\sum_{i<j} |v_i^T v_j| x_i x_j$ and use an MIQP solver.